# Performing interpolation using QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, spatial-analysis, soil

I measured chemical concentration for different types of soil, and I have a picture or map of the distribution of different soils for my studied area. I assume that the concentration will be similar for the same type of soil.

How can I run interpolation analysis for my studied area to map soil concentration taking into consideration the different soil type?

Answer (score 1):

@Julien H, there is a tool in QGIS called **Interpolation** used for performing such analysis. You can find the tool by navigating from the menu **Processing -> Toolbox**. Search for Interpolation. It will give different options.
This is a tutorial [Interpolating Point Data (QGIS3)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/interpolating_point_data.html) from [qgistutorials.com](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/interpolating_point_data.html). It is a good start, it will teach you the basics of perform interpolation analysis.

Comment: thank you for the guidance

Answer (score 1):

Just to name another alternative, there is an algorithm in GRASS which allows you to take the different soil types into account when performing interpolation (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.surf.rst.html)

Comment: thanks for your help !